# empty PIC 3FFF opcode/instruction (PIC12F683)

Tags: microcontroller, pic, opcode

Memory in pic microcontrollers is cleared by ones so we get 3FFF for an empty word (of 14 bits). But 0b11 1111 1111 1111 is `ADDLW 255` according to the datasheet. Why not fill everything with zeros (`NOPs`) or `GOTO 0000h`? What if code execution gets to those 3FFFs, will it get to reset vector `0000h` eventually? If yes will there be any side effects?

Also interrupt vector `0004h` is 3FFF by default, does it mean that the code after it will be executed on interrupt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical [FLASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory) (also EEPROM) memory is erased when all bits of memory are set to the one. During programming of FLASH memory bits can only be set to zero. So before programming of FLASH we must do a special sequence named ***erasing,*** after that the memory is ready to be programmed.

The "0b11 1111 1111 1111" opcode is **ADDLW 255** and ALU should always executed it. Normally compiler translate your program and the programmer program  opcodes to appropriate FLASH memory locations, after that the memory check is made, so don't care about wrong opcode execution!